# NullPointerException when stubbing a test method call with Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I have these 2 lines in a unit test:

```
DefaultMessageListenerContainer defaultMessageListenerContainer = Mockito.mock(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.class);
when(defaultMessageListenerContainer.isRunning()).thenReturn(true);
```

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.isRunning(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:347)
    at xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.MessageProcessorControllerTest.testPing(MessageProcessorControllerTest.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1191)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1116)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1024)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:124)
```

No matter what I do, NPE is thrown on `when` line almost as if the real method is getting called when setting up the stub. I am using mockito v1.10.19. What am i doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
Here is the entire standalone test class:

```
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;   

public class JmsTest {
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer defaultMessageListenerContainer = Mockito.mock(
                DefaultMessageListenerContainer.class);
        when(defaultMessageListenerContainer.isRunning()).thenReturn(true);
    }
}
```

And the exception that is thrown:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.isRunning(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:347)
    at xxxxxxxxxxx.util.JmsTest.test(JmsTest.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1191)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1116)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1024)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Comment: Can you show us your testPing method? And any `@Before` or `@BeforeClass` methods you have?

Comment: Try debugging your code. The null pointer should not be thrown on the "when" line. It must be somewhere else. Can you provide entire test class file that way we can relate the line numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Your `defaultMessageListenerContainer` is not the one being used. The failing one is of type `AbstractJmsListeningContainer`.

You need to make sure that the mocked variable is correctly passed to the class you are trying to test.

Comment: Changing the code to use `AbstractJmsListeningContainer` produces the same result: `AbstractJmsListeningContainer defaultMessageListenerContainer = Mockito.mock(
    AbstractJmsListeningContainer.class);
  when(defaultMessageListenerContainer.isRunning()).thenReturn(true);`

Comment: I added a standalone test class that reproduces the problem. Please see my update.

Answer (score 0):

That's a good one! I'd have expected that test to pass since it seems to only set the expectations and then make no assertions. I guess I'll leave it to a Mockito expert as to why that very simple looking exercise does not work. I'd certainly be interested to know what's behind it. In the meanwhile, if it might be an option for you to use another library, I'll offer this suggestion instead: try JMockit. The following should work out to be roughly equivalent to what you were trying to achieve with Mockito...but the test passes. Good luck!

```
import mockit.Expectations;
import mockit.Mocked;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

public class JmsTest2 {

    @Mocked
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer defaultMessageListenerContainer;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        new Expectations() {{
            defaultMessageListenerContainer.isRunning(); result = true;
        }};
        assertThat(defaultMessageListenerContainer.isRunning()).isTrue();
    }
}
```

EDIT 1:

Looking into this a little more closely, it seems that there's some synchronization in that isRunning() method around an object marked final. Mockito, AFAIK, tends not to be all that helpful in cases where you have objects marked final that you'd like to change. You could try to fight this with PowerMock, or use a different library--I already suggested the one I like--which I think would be a clean and simple way forward for you.

```
protected final Object lifecycleMonitor = new Object();
...
@Override
public final boolean isRunning() {
    synchronized (this.lifecycleMonitor) {
        return (this.running && runningAllowed());
    }
}
```

Comment: I did see that as well. But I was thinking Mockito should not be calling that method period so what's inside of it should not matter.

Comment: Thought this was a good question because your code clearly expressed something that would be possible with Mockito on a collaborating class unencumbered by the constraints imposed by the use of "final". Basically, you find yourself wanting to do exactly what Mockito is intended for (except that footnote about not being able to deal with final methods), but are thwarted. Until I noticed the method you wanted to replace was final, I thought, oh, this should work. Looks like more recent versions of Mockito should be able to do this.